# How can I install python 64 bit on ubuntu 32 bit?

Tags: 16.04, python, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm trying to install python3.6 64-bit to use tensorflow that is no more supporting 32-bit version, but my ubuntu16.04 is 32-bit version

can I do that?

Architecture:          i686

CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit

However, I'm doing so on windows, my windows is 32-bit but i'm already using  python3.6 64-bit and I'm using all packages I need including tensorflow

Anyone have an idea is this option applicable or not!

Comment: You can run 64bit OS with no problems if you have i686 it is newer than i386 but basically the same to confirm run `lscpu` in terminal if you see the architecture x86_64 means it is 64bit and below you can see that it supports 32bit and 64bit. Though at least 2GB of RAM for 64bit is required.

Comment: 32bit systems will disappear soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to install python3.6 64-bit [...] but my ubuntu16.04 is 32-bit version
>   Can I do that?

**No.**
You cannot execute 64-bit code on a 32-bit system (without an emulator - and I don't know of any one which achieves that).

So a 64-bit system is indicated by the following terms:

*** *AMD64*, *EM64T*, *Intel64*, *x86_64* and *x64*.**

They all do mean the same - a 64-bit capable system.

Comment: So, reinstalling ubuntu 16.04 64-bit might cause any problems or my system is compatible?

Comment: Using a 64-bit Ubuntu surely does solve your related problems.

Comment: am just afraid as info mentioned here http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ , as my system is not AMD  @zx485

Comment: What are you afraid of? If your computer does support 64-bit, you can install a 64-bit OS. What's your CPU type?

Comment: my architecture is  i686, and the 64-bit ubuntu said to have arch AMD as mentioned in the website, this will not cause a problem?

Comment: No. What's your processor type? BTW _i686_ is an ancient 32-bit architecture. You say that you don't have an AMD processor, so pick your processor type [here at Intel ARK](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark.html).

Comment: check in terminal `lscpu | grep -i 64`

Comment: mymodel name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2375M CPU @ 1.50GHz

Comment: So, your processor is an [Intel® Core™ i3-2375M Processor](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/74259/intel-core-i3-2375m-processor-3m-cache-1-50-ghz.html), and so it does support `Intel® 64` and you can use a 64-bit OS. Case closed.

Comment: The link is the definite resource for all informations about your processor. It says that you can use a 64-bit Operating System. So if you want to use Python 64-bit, you'd have to use a 64-bit OS - like a 64-bit version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you I will mark your answer as correct. But there is some thing I just need to understand, I can use ubuntu 64bit because my processor supports 64bit, what is the need of the info whether AMD or i686. I got confused when I read that on ubuntu  downlaod page

Comment: I'm talk particlary about this "64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop image:

Choose this if you have a computer based on the AMD64 or EM64T architecture (e.g., Athlon64, Opteron, EM64T Xeon, Core 2)"

Comment: _AMD_ and _Intel_ are similar. If you read about AMD64, it just means that AMD was the first corporation that realized 64-bit technology. So _AMD64_, _EM64T_, _Intel64_, _x86_64_ and _x64_ all do mean the same - a 64-bit capable system.

Comment: And what i686 means? this is my type

Comment: _i686_ is the name of an old 32-bit architecture, the P6 Pentium. [Here, the difference is explained](https://superuser.com/q/238112/427002). Your processor is newer and does support more features.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97119/discussion-between-shrouk-mansour-and-zx485).